# MATLAB: fast creation of vector of indices

Tags: matlab, vector, vectorization

I have a variable `distr=[0 3 1 0 2];`, and I have a variable `full` which should contrain `distr(i)` times `i`, for all `i`.

In this example, i want:

```
full=[2 2 2 3 5 5];
```

because `distr(2)=3`, therefore 3x `2`, and so on.

Of course I can do it in a `for`-loop:

```
full=zeros([1,sum(distr)]);
cc=1;
for i=1:length(distr)
    curr=distr(i);
    full(cc:cc+curr-1)=i*ones([1,curr]);
    cc=cc+curr;
end
```

but that is very slow. Do you know of a fast way, using MATLAB's awesome array-oriented style? Thanks!

Comment: You want __run-length decoding__. Use `repelem` as follows: `result = repelem(1:numel(distr), distr);`. Or see the linked question and answers for other approaches.

Comment: Ah, that is the correct name, i was not able to find results because i didn't know how to call this property. Thank you, that helps - in particular the performance tests there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, but maybe this will work. I can't check it since I currently don't have MATLAB:

```
full_tmp = arrayfun(@(i,n) i*ones(1,n),1:length(distr),distr,'uniformoutput',false);
full = cat(2,full_tmp{:});
```

Comment: oh yes it does :) thank you!!